# Is it possible to get py.test to skip a test if it is running under coverage?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm adding some performance smoke tests to our test suite, and they fail spectacularly when running py.test with coverage. This isn't very surprising, nor an indication of a performance issue (timings under coverage don't relate to anything real..)

How do I mark (ie. `pytest.mark.skipif(..)`) these tests so they're automatically skipped during coverage runs?

I'm using PyCharm during development if it is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be quite doable, using the pytest `config` object. See the very last example on [Skip and xfail](http://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html):

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(not pytest.config.getvalue("db"),
                    reason="--db was not specified")
def test_function(...):
    pass
```

I imagine what you want is just

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(pytest.config.getvalue("--cov"),
                    reason="--cov not compatible with smoke tests")
```

(**ETA:** The destination of `cov` is actually `cov_source`, which is why it didn't recognise `cov`. Putting `--cov` seems like a safer bet as it matches the option you actually type and doesn't require you to know the code internals.)

Comment: If I call `py.test --cov=.` it gives me a `ValueError: no option named 'cov'` is there some other way I should specify coverage so it's picked up by config?

Comment: I guess you are not using [pytest-cov](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov) then. What exact command is being run when you "run py.test with coverage"? I haven't used PyCharm but I imagine it has a console or log where you could find this out.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pytest-cov. I'll be happy if I can get this to work from the command line, i.e. `py.test --cov=. tests` where tests is the test folder. PyCharm uses `C:\srv\venv\dkforms\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\run_coverage.py" run "--omit=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers*" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.4\helpers\pycharm\pytestrunner.py" -p pytest_teamcity C:/srv/lib/dkforms/tests`

Comment: OK I'm a bit confused, do you want to get this working in the command line or through PyCharm?

Comment: That ValueError suggests that your virtualenv is not set correctly when you run py.test on the command line, or the plugin is not being picked up.

Comment: It runs/displays coverage, so I was assuming it was correctly installed (`pip install pytest-cov`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72000/discussion-between-pfctdayelise-and-thebjorn).